# How might we parse the phrase "put [something] out to board" to better understand its meaning?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

The phrase is found in John Cheever's *The Swimmer*:

> He wondered if the Lindleys had sold their houses or gone away for the
> summer and put them out to board.

I understand the phrase to basically mean *rent out*, so that he could have said: *"...or gone away for the summer and rented them out"*.

Are there accepted usages of '**put out**' and '**to board**' that when coupled together yield the meaning '*rent out*'?

It seems Cheever made a mistake here. For '[**board**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/board)' means *"to provide with regular meals and often also lodging usually for compensation"*. But the sentence quoted states that, in the instance of boarding, the owners of the house had left. In that case, it seems they wouldn't be able to provide any meals.

And as for '**put out**', I can't find anything in the dictionaries to suggest it has a history of meaning anything like '*rent out*'.

Comment: One accepted usage might be John Cheever’s *The Swimmer*.  :-)

Comment: Yes, it does seem an odd expression. I would expect _let them [out] for the summer_.

Comment: @KateBunting - I thought of that as well. But the term **let** is chiefly British. On the other hand, I've noticed Cheever use quite a few British terms.

Comment: @Jim - Your statement seems to imply that a term's being accepted is dependent on who says it. In any case, surely a child or ESL learner, who conceivably could have uttered this phrase, would meet with negative criticism from their teachers if they ever said such a thing. And I think such criticism would extend to virtually any cipher who happens to write anything anywhere.

Comment: The expression, while unusual in the specific *out to board* construction, makes sense to me. The owners had left, and their houses might now be used to board other people. Think of it as Airbnb. Or of having some kind of manager overseeing the "meals and lodging" in the owner's absence. Horses get *put out to pasture* so why can't houses get *put out to board*?

Comment: @touchstone - One first has to define “accepted”.  On this site, it is customary to do an ngram search in an English language corpus to ascertain level of usage.  Since you’ve quoted a book, that book will likely show up in the ngram search.  Also note that books (other than self-published) usually go through an editor so the usage in question must have made it past the editor’s desk.  I also don’t see why anyone should be met with negative criticism for saying it.

Comment: Could it be that the owners of the houses employed permanent household staff? If they did then the staff would look after the visitors.